# Porque o console aparece mesmo usando uma biblioteca para criar uma janela?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, codeblocks, sdl

Queria entender porque o console também é aberto quando é feito um programa usando a biblioteca SDL2. Estou usando o codeblocks no windows 10.

Como faz para não aparecer o console e só aparecer a janela gerada através do SDL2?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                                          "Funcionou!",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          800, 600,
                                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,0,0,255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Nunca usei a SDL e por isso posso estar enganado, mas parece que essa aplicação foi feita para console e não para Windows. Entre outras coisas elas deveria usar a `WinMain()` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point. Mas pode ser que ela mesma tenha isso já, mas teria que compilar de uma determinada forma para acontecer isto.

Comment: Na realidade, na versão do SDL2 para o Windows, a `WinMain()` é inicializada "sob o capô", a própria `main` que aparece não é a função `main` que se esperaria em um programa C++ - por exemplo, se você retirar os argumentos `int argc, char** argv` você tem um erro de compilação - mas sim um `define` ou algo que o valha de uma função chamada `SDL_main()`.

Comment: Se estivesse utilizando o msvc era só setar o subsystem como windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser retirar o console no CodeBlock, na tela inicial selecione na barra de menu, o item **project** e então o item **properties**. Então, o programa irá abrir a tela seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa tela, você irá na aba **Build Targets** e então no campo **Type>** você seleciona a opção **Gui application**.Confira-se:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, o console deverá desaparecer.

Por fim, um breve comentário: o console é muito útil na fase de produção para fazer debug, Então, eu só retiro o console quando o programa está pronto.